# How to enable the landscape mode on the default launcher on Android Marshmallow?

Tags: nexus-5, launcher, 6.0-marshmallow, auto-rotation

I can read [on various news websites](https://www.androidpit.com/android-m-release-date-news-features-name) that in Android 6 Marshmallow, it is possible to rotate the screen on the launcher.

I can't find any setting about this on my Nexus 5 and when I activate automatic rotation, it doesn't rotate on the launcher.

Any idea how to enable this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest version of Google Now added a home screen rotation option in its settings. To access the home screen settings, either long-tap on the home screen or choose **Settings** from the Google Now "hamburger menu" (the menu that slides in from the left). **Allow rotation** is the bottom option in the settings.

[Source](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/enable-auto-rotate-for-your-android-home-screen-in-latest-google-app-update/)

Comment: Please link the source backing your answer

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing the feature you claim to have been added in recent update? I don't see any mention of it in *What's new* of app's description.

Comment: source link added. the link also contains screenshots.

Comment: Odfly if you flip the switch in Google Now, it doesn't for the entire home screen. That is a very strange place to place that setting in my opinion.

Comment: @Firelord I've tried the linked instructions on my phone and they work perfectly.

Comment: @HansGruber It looked like your answer was an attempt to reply to this answer, so I've moved it to a comment. Feel free to delete the comment and post a new answer if you want to actually answer the question.

Answer (score 12):

Auto rotate Home screen was one of the top features of [2nd Android M Developer preview](http://www.phone-probe.com/android-m-developer-preview-2-allows-home-screen-rotation/).
I hate to burst the bubble, Auto rotate home screen feature was not incorporated in the final version of Android Marshmallow 6.0.

> We're  disappointed to see that auto rotate support hasn't made it to the home screen, however. In the second developer preview, the Google app added an "allow rotation" option to the home screen settings, which let the home screen rotate like any other app on the system. We loved it. It never made the jump to the final version, though.

[Source](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/10/android-6-0-marshmallow-thoroughly-reviewed/2/)

---

However, if you have got a rooted phone, you can modify *build.prop* file to get this feature.

1. Navigate to and open `/system/build.prop` file using any Root explorers
2. Add `log.tag.launcher_force_rotate=VERBOSE` at the end of the file
3. *Optional step:* Add `lockscreen.rot_override=true` to enable screen rotation in your lock screen
4. Reboot to see the feature working!

[Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6/general/howto-enable-auto-rotation-lock-screen-t2969024)

Answer (score 2):

It works perfect if you follow the directions.  Simply put, touch the google icon,  once it pops up push the hamburger menu,  find settings, scroll all the way down, last item on the list "allow rotation" tick it,  now landscape mode is working,  I know it's working on lollipop, marshmellow,  and Android. N. strange place to place this setting,  but what the hey,  that's why we have hard working and devoted devs and enthusiastic members that look for this stuff.  I've always like landscape home screen.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is a good answer in itself, but it doesn't really add any information that wasn't already in Jude's answer. You can achieve more if you focus on questions that don't already have an accepted answer.